# Can I load the 'Roles' attribute of an <asp:RoleGroup> programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, roles

I'm maintaining an ASP.NET application, and right now security is defined in various places throughout the site. There is some logic in the code-behind, like `if User.IsInRole(...)`, and there is other logic sprinkled throughout the ASPX pages like:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lvDoSomeStuff" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Accounting,HR,Blah">
        ...
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

As new feature requests come in and new roles are created, I am forced to go through the entire application and make sure I haven't missed any areas. I'd like to avoid this in the future.

How can I set the `Roles` attribute of the `<asp:RoleGroup>` element programmatically? I've tried doing something like this:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lvDoSomeStuff" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="<%= UserManager.GetRolesThatCanDoX() %>">
        ...
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

where `GetRolesThatCanDoX()` returns a comma-delimited list of role names, but my method never seems to get called.

Is it possible to do something like this in ASP.NET WebForms? Please help me decouple my code! ;-)

**Solution:** [Phantomtypist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106142/can-i-load-the-roles-attribute-of-an-asproelgroup-programmatically/5106195#5106195) worked perfectly. My implementation of it was as follows:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lvDoSomeStuff" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup>
        ...
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load rolegroups from UserManager
    lvDoSomeStuff.RoleGroups[0].Roles = UserManager.GetRolesThatCanDoStuff().ToArray();
    lvDoSomeOtherStuff.RoleGroups[0].Roles = UserManager.GetRolesThatCanDoOtherStuff().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like this...

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RoleGroup rg = new RoleGroup();
    rg.ContentTemplate = new CustomTemplate();
    String[] RoleList = {"users"};
    rg.Roles = RoleList;
    RoleGroupCollection rgc = LoginView1.RoleGroups;
    rgc.Add(rg);

}
```

Designer:

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
     <AnonymousTemplate>
         You are not logged in.<br />
         <asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus>
     </AnonymousTemplate>
     <LoggedInTemplate>
          You are logged in as
          <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="server" />. This message is not from the template.<br />
          <asp:LoginStatus id="Loginstatus2" runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus>
     </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Wow, OK, I didn't even _try_ to set the 'Roles' attribute from code-behind. I figured it'd be _easier_ to do from the ASPX page. Bad idea ;-)